# TamperMonkey Script

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I am trying to change a `<textarea>` field in an HTML login page into an `<input>` field, dynamically, on page load.

```
<div class="field input-field">
    <span class="user-icon">
    </span>
    <textarea class="qStr" data-qstrph="LDAP_SERVER_STR12" id="username" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username">
    </textarea>
    <span class="reset-icon slice-img">
    </span>
</div>
```

The first thing I thought of was [TamperMonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/), and using JavaScript to do this.

I reached out to a friend of mine, who is far more talented than I am, and asked him to make a small JavaScript bit to do what I'm wanting. He quickly came back with this:

```
const originalItem = document.getElementById("username")
const newItem = document.createElement("input")
newItem.setAttribute("type", "text")
newItem.setAttribute("class", "qStr")
newItem.setAttribute("data-qstrph", "LDAP_SERVER_STR12") 
newItem.setAttribute("id", "username")
newItem.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off")
newItem.setAttribute("placeholder", "Username")
originalItem.replaceWith(newItem)
```

When I run this snippet in the Chrome developer console, it does exactly what you'd expect it to do, and that's awesome! When I take the same block and put it into TamperMonkey, save the file, and make sure its an enabled script, and reload the HTML page -- nothing happens -- and this makes me sad:

Here is the code, as it is in TamperMonkey:

[image: A screenshot showing code from a tampermonkey script]

I'm not sure what I'm not doing right, as the code worked perfectly in the dev console.

Your input is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The script is likely running before the DOM has loaded the elements you are trying to access. Is there a way to delay the script until the DOM is ready? If not, you should wrap your function in a handler for the [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event to prevent it from running before the DOM is ready.

Comment: Nevermind, looking at the [Tampermonkey docs](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_run_at), the default when no `@run-at` tag is provided is `@run-at document-idle` which runs after the document loads.